# SoundManager 2 - only create one sound object per URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, soundcloud, es6-promise, soundmanager2

I am using SoundManager2 to play audio retrieved from SoundCloud. My issue arises when there are multiple of the same track on one page since I only want to create one sound object for each URL.

It seems that upon initialization of each SCPlayer there is not another SoundManager instance in the window since `this.player` is always null. I think this has something to do with the promise made by the soundcloud client (since its asynchronous) but not know how to go about resolving the issue.

```
var SCPlayer = function(id, url){
    this.playing = false;
    this.id = id;
    this.elems = $(".player[data-sc-id="+ this.id + "]"); //Find all elems with data attr so all controls of the same sound are affected
    this.btns = this.elems.find(".button");
    this.url = url;
    this.player = window.soundManager.getSoundById('sc_' + this.id); //always null
    this.init()
};

SCPlayer.prototype = {
    init: function(){
        var that = this;
        if (! that.player) {
            that.player = window.soundManager.createSound({
                id: 'sc_' + that.id,
                url: that.url,
                autoLoad: false,
                autoPlay: false
            });
        }
        $(this.btns).on('click', {context: this}, this.onClick);
    },
    onClick: function(ev){
        //Change play controls
    }
};

var init_SCPlayers = function(){
    //Loop through each player element, retrieve the stream url
    //and then create the soundmanager object
    var urls = [];
    $('.player.sc-player').each(function(){
        var id = $(this).data('sc-id');
        SC.get('/tracks/' + id + '/streams').then(function(stream) {
            new SCPlayer(id, stream.http_mp3_128_url)
        });
    })
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve an existing sound from SoundManager2 using getSoundById. The docs for SoundManager2 are [here](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/doc/).

```
that.player = soundManager.getSoundById('sc_' + that._id) || soundManager.createSound(...);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: I'm not sure the edit actually did much, because once a person has the function name they can look it up in the docs.